# useParams returns string/undefined

Tags: reactjs, router

I have a problem where using `react-router useParams` returns `string | undefined` for some reason. Let me walk you through my code.

I have a JSON file with an array of objects.

In one component I have mapped through that array:

```
  {coursesList.map((item, i) => (
                <div key={i}>
                  <Link to={`/courses/${item.id}`}>
                    <CourseCard
                      duration={item.duration}
                      available={item.available}
                      image={item.image}
                      title={item.title}
                      category={item.category}
                      text={item.text}
                    />
                  </Link>
                </div>
              ))}
```

Clicking on single course should lead to page where there are details about that special course.
In that component I have used `useParams()`.

```
  const { itemId } = useParams();
  const thisCourse = coursesList.find((item) => item.id === itemId);
```

`thisCourse` will be used to display information from the selected course.
But when I put `<h2>{thisCourse.title}</h2>` it returns error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')`

`coursesList` is imported via `import coursesList from "../CoursesList.json";`

In `App.js` I have declared routes.

```
 <Route path="/courses" element={<Courses />}></Route>
 <Route path="/courses/:itemId" element={<SingleCourse />}></Route>
```

**UPDATE**

Single Course component code

```
import coursesList from "../CoursesList.json";

const SingleCourse = () => {
  const { itemId } = useParams();
  const thisCourse = itemId
    ? coursesList.find((item) => item.id === itemId)
    : null;

  return (
    <>
      <header className="header-courses small-header">
        <Navbar />
        <div className="second-header-text">
          {thisCourse?.id ? (
            <h2>{thisCourse.title}</h2>
          ) : (
            <h2>Title not found</h2>
          )}
        </div>
      </header>
     <main>
        <section>Single Card content</section>
     </main>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: What if an item with that id _isn't_ found in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useParams will always return string | undefined for keys

You need to make sure that you check if it exists first.

```
  const thisCourse = itemId? coursesList.find((item) => item.id === itemId) : null;
```

Also check if thisCourse exists before rendering anything from it

```
{thisCourse?.id? 
<RenderSomething/> : <p>Not found</p>
}
```

If you don't get itemId at all, check your url. It should look like this: `"example.com/courses/123"`

UPDATE:

Turns out that item.id was a number, and it always returned undefined as it was compared with a string.

So parsing item.id as a string (item.id.toString()) or itemId as a number (+itemId) was the solution

Comment: Thank you. thisCourse always returns undefined for some reason. 

My URL is okay, I always get id from that specific course in the url.

Comment: Then something is wrong with your SingleCourse component. Can you update the post with that code included?

Comment: Will do now. Watch out. Thank you!

Comment: What do you get if you console.log(coursesList)

Comment: It's a JSON file, array with objects, when I console.log it returns array of objects, nothing is undefined.

Comment: Since it is a JSON file, you might need to parse it first: JSON.parse(coursesList).find...

Comment: I've tried that already but always get error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1'

Comment: There are two more things that you can try. If item.id is a number, you need to convert it to a string. since number !== string, so It cant find it. Best to console.log the "item" in coursesList.find out. you can use typeof item.id

Comment: Damn. this is it! I didn't thinking good, my Id was number. With simple toString() method I got it solved! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In `<Route path="/courses/:itemId" element={<SingleCourse />}></Route>`, remove `/`, instead of `courses/:itemId`, use `courses:itemId`.

Still error? Change path name.

```
 <Route path="/courses" element={<Courses />}></Route>
 <Route path="/course:itemId" element={<SingleCourse />}></Route> // No courses, just course
```

Comment: Still get the same error..

Comment: Can you show error code, or error message?

Comment: I solved it. item.id was number and I needed to convert it to String since i was triple checking with '===' . But thank you!